# php variables inside json results in invalid json

Tags: php, json

I have the following json created dynamically using php variables and it gives me:

```
{"message":"invalid json"}
```

Code:

```
$json = '{
"sex": "'.$gender.'",
"age": '.$age.',
"evidence": [
{"id": "'.$symptom_id1.'", "choice_id": "present", "initial": true}, 
{"id": "'.$symptom_id2.'", "choice_id": "present", "initial": true},
{"id": "p_7", "choice_id": "'.$test1.'"},
{"id": "p_8", "choice_id": "'.$test2.'"}, 
{"id": "p_9", "choice_id": "'.$test3.'"},
{"id": "p_10", "choice_id": "'.$test4.'"},
{"id": "p_28", "choice_id": "'.$test5.'"},
{"id": "'.$location.'", "choice_id": "present"}
],
"extras": {
"disable_groups": true
}
}';
$ch = curl_init('https://api.infermedica.com/v2/diagnosis');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json),
'app_id: '. APP_ID,
'app_key: '. APP_KEY,
'Interview-Id: '.$interview_id,
'User-Id: '. $hasheduser_id
]);                                                                                                                   
$result = curl_exec($ch);

echo '<pre>';
print_r( $result );
echo '</pre>';
```

**Hard coding the values in place of variables works fine**. Being a newbie, I am unable to understand the reason why it is not well formed.

Help requested.

Comment: That's horrible. Don't try to produce JSON by mashing strings together. Create a proper data structure and run it through `json_encode`.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] - you have missing variables, we have no way to telling what the resulting JSON looks like. (For that matter, you should *look* at the resulting JSON and run it through a linter).

Comment: First create array after json_encode () method use.

Comment: Please note that If i know how to do it, i would not have requested help.

Answer (score 1):

You should never try and create valid JSON on your own, it will only lead to security issues and bugs, instead use a data structure and pass it to `json_encode`.

Example data structure for your use:

```
$to_json = [
  'sex' => $gender,
  'age' => $age,
  'evidence' => [
    ['id' => $symptom_id1, 'choice_id' => 'present', 'initial' => true],
    ['id' => $symptom_id2, 'choice_id' => 'present', 'initial' => true],
    ['id' => 'p_7', 'choice_id' => $test_1],
    ['id' => 'p_8', 'choice_id' => $test_2],
    ['id' => 'p_9', 'choice_id' => $test_3],
    ['id' => 'p_10', 'choice_id' => $test_4],
    ['id' => 'p_28', 'choice_id' => $test_5],
    ['id' => $location, 'choice_id' => 'present'],
  ],
  'extras' => [
    'disabled_groups' => true
  ],
];
```

Then encode it:

```
$json = json_encode($jo_json);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: still getting the invalid json message.

Comment: Can you ``echo json_last_error_msg()`` after ``json_encode`` and see what the error is.

Comment: If there is no error then the JSON you are sending to the service could be incorrect, i.e. doesn't follow what they expect to see.

Comment: Yes. var_dump(json_last_error(), json_last_error_msg()); 
gives:
int(0) string(8) "No error"

Comment: I had an error in the array, ``['id' => 'p_28', 'choice_id' => $test_5],``, should've been ``['id' => 'p_28', 'choice_id' => $test_5],``, don't know if that is much of an issue.

Comment: But hardcoding the values in my original code gives expected results.

Comment: 'disable_groups' was wrong too..but it did not make any change.

Comment: Receive the message {"message":"empty query"}

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is invalid due to a typo on the 2nd line of your variable.

```
"age": '.$age.',
```

should be

```
"age": "'.$age.'",
```

Or what would be better

```
"age": "$age",
```

But the best way to accomplish what you are attempting to do would be to create a PHP array, and pass this to json_encode.

```
$array = ['hello, i am a key'=>'i am some data'];
var_dump(json_encode($array));
```